# Javascript: Grunt uglify error on json variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parse-platform, gruntjs

I making an app with angularjs and parse.com rest api.

Everythings work perfect but when "build" with grunt I have the error on uglify task.

the code:

```
service.create(token,{      
    tipo:$scope.datos.tipo,
    raza:$scope.datos.raza,
    title:$scope.datos.titulo,
    descrip:$scope.datos.descrip,
    contact:$scope.datos.contact,
    ACL: {
      [userid] : { "read": true, "write": true },  // <-- error on variable
      "*" : {"read": true}
    }
})
```

How I can solve this problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those square brackets are your problem, it's invalid syntax unless you are using ES6 where uglify doesn't have ES6 support yet.

Comment: ok, the simple solution, I can think of;  I'll delete the brackets. run uglify task then add brackets again.